# How can I create 2 'columns' layout within a UIView

Tags: ios

I have a Cell.xib which is for each cell in a Table View.
In the Cell.xib, I have a UIView and my question is how can I create 2 'columns' within the UIView?

```
-----------------------------------------
| UILabel1            UILabel2          |
| UILabel3            UILabel4          |
-----------------------------------------
```

How can I make UILabel2 and UILabel4 to start at half of the width of the parent UIView?

Comment: You have two options, one view with two tableview or one table view with a cell with two column. Here some help to this second:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137756/ios-how-to-make-multiple-column-table/27138156#27138156

Comment: If you can try the first option let me know. Of course the behavior is different.

Comment: Use auto layout to place you views. Labels 2 and 4 should have a constraint from their left edge to the superview's centerX.

Comment: How can I specify the Label2,4 constraint to superview's centerX? I do that in xib editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a constraint between the left edge of your label and the center of the superview, select the label, and choose "Horizontal Center in Container" from the align menu. Double click on that constraint in the size inspector to edit it. I use the pull down menu to first switch the first and second item (if necessary to make the label the first item), and then change it from centerX to leading. The constraint should look like this when you're done,

[image]